# How to upload the file content that is inside a variable with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

How to send 'data' which is the file content with ajax ?
How do I setup the name of that file ?

I'm looking to do it without the DOM "form/input"

```
<script>

var file_to_upload = "hi I'm the content of a file";

$.ajax({
    url: 'php/upload.php',
    data: file_to_upload,
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});

<script>
```

Comment: I don't think jQuery has built-in support for posting files via ajax. [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) does though (and is built into modern browsers), because `body` can be a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), and the `File` object you get from a `FileList` on an `input` element is a `Blob`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously) or [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload).

Comment: no, this isn't what I'm asking

Comment: Please take the time to ensure that your question is clear and complete before posting.

Comment: I did, what's not clear ? I'll clarify

Answer (score 0):

I don't think jQuery has built-in support for posting files via ajax. [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) does though (and is built into modern browsers), because body can be a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) or a [`BufferSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BufferSource) (`ArrayBuffer` or typed array).

You can either send the blob or buffer as the body of the request, or if you want to send it as a named parameter in a multipart form upload, you can create a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instance and use a `Blob` as the value when calling [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append). Something like:

```
// This is off the top of my head, not meant to be a perfect,
// all-singing, all-dancing example. You'll need to read the
// linked documentation and adjust as necessary.
var blob = new Blob([/*...file data...*/], {type: "appropriate/mimetype"});
var data = new FormData();
data.append("parameterName", blob);
fetch("php/upload.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: data
})
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.text(); // or perhaps response.json()
})
.then(result => {
    // ...use the response
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report the error
});
```

`/*...file data...*/` can be a typed array, an `ArrayBuffer`, etc.; see [the `Blob` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) for details.

Or if this is within an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
try {
    let blob = new Blob([/*...file data...*/], {type: "appropriate/mimetype"});
    let form = new FormData();
    data.append("parameterName", blob);
    let response = await fetch("php/upload.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: data
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
    }
    let result = await response.text(); // or perhaps response.json()
    })
    // ...use the response
} catch(error) {
    // ...handle/report the error
}
```